# Como faço para retornar uma nova instância da própria classe em python dinamicamente dentro dela?

Tags: python, classes, imutabilidade

Estou dando uma estudada em `Python` e para isso estou montando uma classe no Python que eu já tinha feito em PHP.

Por exemplo, em um determinado método em `PHP` eu precisava retornar a mesma instância da classe, dinamicamente, porém sem usar o  `$this` (que faz referência a instância atual do objeto), pois quero aplicar a imutabilidade nesse caso.

Exemplo:

```
class Time {

        public function diff(Time $time) {
              $seconds = abs($time->getSeconds() - $this->getSeconds());

              return new static(0, 0, $seconds);
        }
}
```

Ou seja, que um determinado método retorna a instância da própria classe, porém não a mesma instância, mas uma  nova.

Em python eu tenho isso atualmente:

```
class Time(object):

    __seconds = 0

    def __init__(self, **kw):

        self.set_time(**kw)

    def set_time(self, **kw):

        seconds = (kw.get('hours', 0) * 3600) \
        + (kw.get('minutes', 0) * 60) \
        + kw.get('seconds', 0)

        self.__seconds = seconds

        return self

   def diff(self, other):
      seconds = abs(self.get_seconds() - other.get_seconds())

      #como posso fazer para retornar uma nova instância com 'seconds' aqui?
```

Answer (score 3):

Acabei descobrindo como resolver esse problema.

Basta utilizar o atributo especial `__class__` da classe atual, que é possível criar uma nova instância.

Exemplo:

```
 class Time(object):

     def diff(self, other):

        seconds = abs(self.get_seconds() - other.get_seconds());

        return self.__class__(seconds=seconds)
```

Assim, se eu herdar, em algum objeto, a classe `Time`, não será necessário recriar o método `diff`, pois o mesmo já obtem o nome da classe dinamicamente através de `__class__`

```
class NewTime(Time):
    pass

a = NewTime(seconds=5)

b = NewTime(seconds=2)

c = a.diff(b)

print (c.__class__) #<class '__main__.NewTime'>
```

Comment: sim  -  `self.__class__` ou `type(self) ` - os dois fazem a mesma coisa. EM Python 3, você pode também usar a variável magica `__class__` dentro de um método (sem o `self` ) : `__class__`  sóziho sempre vai apontar para a própria classe em que o método está definido - mesmo que `self` seja uma instãncia de uma sub-classe da mesma. Esse  `__class__` mágico (por que aparece do nada) faz parte do mecanismo usado em Python 3 para que  `super` funcione sem parâmetros.

Comment: Só uma dúvida @jsbueno: Se eu usar o `__future__`, tem como fazer isso no Python 2 sem o self?

Comment: Não  -essa funcionalidade não foi portada retroativametne para Python2.
Mas até aí, por que vocẽ está usando Python2 em 2016 mesmo?  (Até 2015 eu entenderia).

Comment: @jsbueno sério? agora já podemos ir para o `Python 3`? É que no meu ubuntu, por padrão está instalado o `2.7`

Comment: Faz anos no Ubuntu - mutos anos - que você pdoe ter o Python2  e 3 paralelos - é só instlaar com apt-get install python3 .

Ai, para cada projeto, você instala os requisitos separadametne usando virtualenv e pip (não use pacotes do sistema)  <-   essa prática também é recomendada para proejtos em Python2.

Comment: A questão é mais ou menso subjetiva, amas até 2014, muitas das bibliotecas e frameorks mais importantes do Python nao funcionavam em Python3 ainda -ou não funcionavam direito. Hoje, pratciamente nenhum projeto importante que seja base para desenvolvimento (diferente de aplicativo para o usuário final)  está preso só em Python2

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi o problema, basta retornar uma nova instância da própria classe. Dei uma alterada em algumas coisas da sua classe para executar e mostrar o resultado:

```
class Time(object):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        self.__seconds = 0 
        self.set_time(**kw)

    def set_time(self, **kw):
        seconds = (kw.get('hours', 0) * 3600) \
        + (kw.get('minutes', 0) * 60) \
        + kw.get('seconds', 0)
        self.__seconds = seconds
        return self

    def diff(self, other):
        seconds = abs(self.get_seconds() - other.get_seconds())
        return Time(**{'seconds':seconds})

    def get_seconds(self):
        return self.__seconds

x = {'hours':1, 'minutes':2, 'seconds':1}
t = Time(**x)
print t.get_seconds()

x2 = {'hours':1, 'minutes':0, 'seconds':0}
t2 = Time(**x2)
print t2.get_seconds()

t3 = t.diff(t2)
print t3.get_seconds()
```

Saída:

```
3721
3600
121
```

Comment: Ok, mas suponhamos que eu acabo de herdar a classe `Time`. Eu teria que alterar o método `diff` toda vez que tivesse uma herança?

Comment: Não.. o método diff é da classe Time e vai sempre retornar uma nova instância dela própria. Se quiser que o método retorne outra coisa, ele precisa ser reimplementado na classe que está herando

Comment: Errado, tem uma outra forma de fazer isso em Python

Comment: Então eu não entendi o problema ou não conheço essa outra forma. Vou acompanhar esse tópico para ver se alguém sabe. Desculpa não ter conseguido ajudar.

Comment: Do jeito que você fez antende, mas na verdade eu estou falando que o problema é gerado quando você herda essa classe. Vai continuar retornando `Time`, daí eu teria que reescrever o método. Da maneira que eu fiz na nova resposta, resolve

Comment: O jeito que o próprio Wallace faz funciona - a nova instância criada é da subclasse. Você tanto pode user  `self.__class__()` como `type(self)()`